# i am getting an error while calling ckeditor5 component in vue 3 composition api <script setup>

Tags: configuration, vuejs3, components, ckeditor5

Component name is `contenteditor.vue`.

As you can see I am struggling with component calling. I am using bootstrap 5 for styling.

```
<template>
    <div>
      <CKEditor :editor="ClassicEditor" v-model="editorData" :config="editorConfig"></CKEditor>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script setup>
  import { ref, watch, defineProps, defineEmits } from 'vue';
  import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';
  import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';
  import Image from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/image';
  import Alignment from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment';
  
  const { modelValue } = defineProps(['modelValue']);
  const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue']);
  const editorData = ref(modelValue);
  const editorConfig = ref({
    plugins: [Image, Alignment],
    toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote', 'imageUpload', 'alignment'],
    heading: {
      options: [
        { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Paragraph', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
        { model: 'heading1', view: 'h1', title: 'Heading 1', class: 'ck-heading_heading1' },
        { model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title: 'Heading 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2' },
      ],
    },
  });
  
  watch(editorData, (newValue) => {
    emit('update:modelValue', newValue);
  });
  </script>
```

Here I am calling my component but it is not working:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <h1>My Editor</h1>
      <Contenteditor  v-model="editorContent" />
  
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script setup>
  import Contenteditor from '../../components/contenteditor.vue';
  import { ref } from 'vue';
  
  const editorContent = ref('');
  </script>
```

I need to call the component and insert and retrieve the data inside the ckeditor